# automate TGT renewal

Tags: kerberos, gssapi

I’m automating a service that needs to access a kerberized resource.
Passwordless `kinit` with a keytab works fine. The resource is then connected
to using SASL.

Is there a way, maybe via GSSAPI or libkrb5, to ensure a TGT is present
whenever the resource is being accessed? Forking `kinit` before every access
seems the pragmatic thing to do. However, there’s an obvious race between the
time of TGT acquisition and its use to acquire a TGS that I’d like to avoid.

I imagine something like receiving an fd for authentication whose validity is
guaranteed until it is being closed by the user.

I’d prefer to stay away from heavy-duty solutions like *sssd* to auto-renew the
TGT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turns out to be providing the *client* keytab for libkrb5 in the
`KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME` parameter:

```
If no existing tickets are available for the desired name, but the name
has an entry in the default client keytab, the krb5 mechanism will
acquire initial tickets for the name using the default client keytab.
```

From the [MIT Kerberos docs](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/krb_appldev/gssapi.html).

The wiki also has a [write-up of the implementation](https://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Projects/Keytab_initiation).